# Add +x for each item variable

Tags: javascript, numbers, each

I've a little problem.

```
...
         html.push('<table>');
                    html.push('<tr style="background: #CCC;">');
                    html.push('<th>Num</th>');
                    html.push('</tr>');

        $.each(data.items, function(index, d){
        var Num = Num +10;
        html.push("<td>",Num, "</td>");

        etc...
        }
        html.push('</table>');
    ...
```

In PHP I have this function,

```
$num = $num+10;
```

It's not working in javascript.

```
var Num = Num +10;
```

thanks

Comment: You have a typo: `html.push("<td>",Num, "</td>");` should be `html.push("<td>" + Num + "</td>");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redeclaring `Num` in each loop iteration, effectively setting the value to the same value each time.

Try moving the declaration outside of the loop and incrementing it within:

```
var Num = 0;
$.each(data.items, function(index, d){
    Num = Num + 10;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use your index??? use it in your code like this, instead of creating cross scope variables:

```
$.each(data.items, function(index, d){
    var Num = index*10;
    html.push("<td>",Num, "</td>");

    etc...
}
```